# Laravel garbage collector

Tags: php, laravel

Today, a website I built few months ago with Laravel suddenly crashed,

Turns out the `cache` folder of Laravel took the entire 7GB of space I had available on my cloud instance and caused the crash...

The directory taking all of the space was `storage/framework/cache` which had like hundreds of folders with 2-3 letter names.

I assumed such a mature framework would certainly take care of these things!

My question is, should I set a cron job to clear the cache daily, or there is another way? maybe some Laravel configuration that I'm not aware of?!

Comment: I think may be you overuse cache. Make sure that you have set `ttl` to these caches.

Comment: And if u r really need those caches, may be u can use redis driver. And with the business grows, you can build the distributed redis cache for that.

Comment: that is your cache store, what are you caching?

Comment: @lagbox I am not caching anything myself... didn't change any cache configuration either, I also can't run `php artisan optimize` because I have closures in my route. so nothing is cached by me.

Answer (score 0):

I was asking this myself and found this package:

https://github.com/jdavidbakr/laravel-cache-garbage-collector

which looks like a simple solution to me.

you can run it via scheduler: `$schedule->command('cache:gc')->weekly();`